# How do I replace a string in Javascript using webpack

Tags: webpack

I have code in a react app that needs to call out to a service on a different domain. I need a way of updating this when I go between environments. Because it is in the client side JS I think this needs to be done using webpack. My code currently looks like this...

```
const URL = "http://localhost:3030"
...
axios.get(`${URL}/search?searchString=${text}`).then(...)
```

I already use webpack-merge so I already have different configs for the environments I just need to change this string every time.

Answer (score 0):

This loader managed to work for me...

https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader

I implemented it like this...

```
{
  test: /myFile\.js$/,
  loader: 'string-replace-loader',
  options: {
    search: 'TOREPLACE',
    replace: 'REPLACEMENT',
  }
}
```

This will then replace the text as required in the question.

As far as I can tell the library has an MIT license and is free to use.